# JQPlot - How to change the cursor to pointer on Hover to Bar in JQPlot?

Tags: jqplot

I want to change the cursor to 'Pointer' when it hover to Bar of the JQPlot.

I have tried to change in the CSS. But it didn't work. Please help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need - as you tried - to modify it using CSS.
You maybe have not applying CSS change on the right element, you need to apply it to **.jqplot-event-canvas** :

```
$('#chart1').on('jqplotDataHighlight', function () {
   $('.jqplot-event-canvas').css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );
});
```

Please see a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/6gGZt/2/)

**Edit** Fiddle and code updated according to **sdespont**'s comment.

**PS** As written by Lukas Jelinek, you can redefine default pointer when you unhighlight your data :

```
$('#chart1').on('jqplotDataUnhighlight', function() {
    $('.jqplot-event-canvas').css('cursor', 'auto');
});
```

Comment: Good answer, but use .on() instead of .bind() which is deprecated

Comment: Note that at least for line graphs, you must have highlightMouseOver set to true in the series_options otherwise this solution does not work.

Answer (score 2):

As wrote AnthonyLeGovic, bind it using:

```
$('#chart1').on('jqplotDataHighlight', function () {
   $('.jqplot-event-canvas').css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );
});
```

but don't forget to unbind it too to set the normal cursor when you move out:

```
$('#chart1').on('jqplotDataUnhighlight', function() {
    $('.jqplot-event-canvas').css('cursor', 'auto');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer.

Same thing we can do by this way also :

cursor: {
            style: 'pointer',
            show: true,
            showTooltip: false 
        }

But i want the Cursor:"Pointer" should be displayed when it is on the bar not on the whole chart area.